# How to upsidedown tab tag in notebook in by using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m setting up a Notebook by using tkinter,
the tab tags shows like T T, is there a way to upsidedown the tag , make it to I__I ?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('TNotebook', tabposition='ws')

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root, style='TNotebook')
f1 = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='red', width=200, height=200)
f2 = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='blue', width=200, height=200)
notebook.add(f1, text='Frame 1')
notebook.add(f2, text='Frame 2')
notebook.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**See here:**

[image]

Comment: You mean put the tabs on the bottom? Just use `tabposition='s'`.

Comment: the thing is that i already put the tabs on the bottom, but i need to upsidedown the tag, make it like  |__|__|__|  style, usually， they displays  like T T T T style

Comment: by the way, i'm using a scidgreen themedTk

Comment: No idea what you mean by `|__|__|__|`, or `T T T T` style - can you make a drawing, or take a screenshot of what you have, and what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I can just suggest you a workaround -

- go to http://www.upsidedowntext.com/ and get inverted letters.
- copy the letters and paste it into your tab tags fields.
- I've checked in pycharm and it's working fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh man, I'm sorry for my bad description，I don't need to upsidedown the text, but the tag style change it from |''''|''''|''''| to |,,,,|,,,,|,,,,|